# TypeError: csv.fromPath is not a function

Tags: node.js, csv, express, fast-csv

I'm using **fast-csv** to read my csv file but it gives me error like this

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: csv.fromPath is not a
>   function

Here is my code:

```
const fileRows = [];
console.log("req.file.path",req.file.path)
// open uploaded file
csv.fromPath(req.file.path)
  .on("data", function (data) {
    fileRows.push(data); // push each row
  })
  .on("end", function () {
    console.log(fileRows);
    //fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path);   // remove temp file

    const validationError = validateCsvData(fileRows);
    if (validationError) {
      return res.status(403).json({ error: validationError });
    }
    //else process "fileRows" and respond
    return res.json({ message: "valid csv" })
  })
```

Comment: Have you imported the required npm package ? `const csv = require('fast-csv');`

Comment: @RajithaWarusavitarana Yes without it node server is not getting started

Answer (score 11):

for 'fast-csv' version >= 3.0.0 :-  fromPath deprecated in favor of parseFile i.e.
csv.fromPath() changed to csv.parseFile()

for more detail visit : https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv/blob/master/History.md